# R (splm): Is there any way to do an unbalanced panel estimation for spatial econometrics?

Tags: r, spatial-economics

From what I know, `splm` package won't allow us to estimate unbalanced dataset on spatial econometrics (SAR, SEM, SDM). Is there any packages or solution to face unbalanced dataset on spatial econometrics?

Thanks in advance